# Python Pandas Dataframe: Fast way to clean and manipulate data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have multiple time series dataframes where I keep having to do the same things such as:
name the columns, drop columns, add columns, perform operations on columns, perform numpy.select operations on columns, remove columns(lately I have been using a second dataframe with the now unneeded columns).

Is there anyway I can create a function doing these things without me having to keep copying and pasting the code to get my data ready?

Slightly pseudocode example:

## cleaning

```
cols = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep='\t',names=cols)
dcol=['volume']
df.drop(dcol,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

## multiple of these

`df.insert(loc=5,column='name1',value=(df['operation']-df['operation']))`

## second df (used for hiding the values from the main df)

`df2 = df.copy()`

## again, mulitple of these

`df2.insert(loc=6,column='name2',value=(df['operation']-df['operation']))`

## using numpy to select values from df2 to insert them into main df

```
import numpy as np
conditions = [(cond1),(cond2)]
values1 = [(value1),(value2)]
values2 = [(value1),(value2)]
values3 = [(value1),(value2)]

# and finally three of these
df['randomname'] = np.select(conditions,values1)
```

So, is there a fast way to do this? Or I just need to pull myself up by the bootstraps...

Comment: Well, sure, you can write a function that accepts an input dataframe and massages it as you like and returns another. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions if writing functions in Python isn't familiar.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a read now. I apply functions after the fact to my dataframes, but to write a function that does what I asked in my question I don't have a clue!

Comment: Not going to answer my own question yet as I am not trying this out right now, however... May have what I need for this question here: 
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/01/cleaner-data-analysis-pandas-pipes.html

Answer (score 2):

Done! So, we want to create functions doing our tedious tasks and later use df.pipe() with the functions in.
(I'm using pseudocode again on operations)

## standard for my csv files

(not using functions or pipe here)

```
cols = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']
df = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv',sep='\t',names=cols)
```

## insert columns and as many as you wish

```
def insert_cols(data):
    data.insert(loc=6,column='yourCol',value=(data['a']-data['b']))
```

## using numpy.select in function

```
def numpy_cols(data):
    conditions = [data(cond1),data(cond2)]
    values1 = [data(value1),data(value2)]

    data['yourCol2'] = np.select(conditions,values1)
```

## dropping columns in function

```
def drop_cols(data):
    dcols = ['volume','randomName']
    data.drop(dcols,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

## and finally, applying functions through pipe to the df

(and other dfs with same format!)

```
df.pipe(insert_cols)
df.pipe(numpy_cols)
df.pipe(drop_cols)
```

There is a way to apply all your functions in one go using pipe, but I could not get it to work.

I used these websites, and the first one is what made it click:

https://data-flair.training/blogs/pandas-function-applications/

https://towardsdatascience.com/using-pandas-pipe-function-to-improve-code-readability-96d66abfaf8

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/01/cleaner-data-analysis-pandas-pipes.html

EDIT:
I just used a single function containing all necessary cleaning and manipulation, and then just piped that function to the dataframe. Works the same but doing it in a single line (no need to use .pipe() multiple times).